# Configuring Redis on Windows

Tags: windows, redis

I'm using the [MsOpenTech](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) version of Redis on a Windows 2008 server. I've installed via the RedisWatcher Service as described [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-with-Redis-Running-on-a-Windows-Azure-Virtual-Machine), and this is working fine - the server is responding and data going in and out nicely, running multiple instances etc - so great.

I have one problem though - i'm attempting to use a `redis.conf` file to set some default configuration; the `.conf` file being stored in the same directory as `redis-server.exe`, namely `c:\redis\bin`

The config changes themselves are straighforward, i'm simply setting timeout to 20 seconds, thus:

```
timeout 20
```

but when I run the watcher service, connect to the server via the command line and do `config get timeout`, it returns `0`

I've tried to restart the watcher service after making the updates to config. I've tried passing in the timeout value directly in the watcher.conf file for the service, like

```
cmdparms --timeout 20
```

and this doesn't work. I've attempted the same on a second instance, same results.

Interestingly, if I start a second instance of the redis server within the watcher, thus:

```
{
workingdir c:\redis\inst2
runmode hidden
saveout 1
cmdparms --port 6380
}
```

this works, respecting the `--port` argument and kicking off a second instance at port 6380. Although as mentioned above, passing a `--timeout` parameter or a config file parameter to this instance is not working either.

Setting configuration via the command line works fine, ie, when connected to redis:

```
config set timeout 20
```

This sets the timeout as expected, but obviously doesn't persist the setting beyond that session. This being version 2.6 of redis, I don't have access to the config rewrite command, so can't get around it that way.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Use Chocolatey instead. Works smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer was simple. Restarting the `RedisWatcher` service does not restart the `redis-server.exe` process.

Manually stopping this process and restarting via the watcher made the config changes be picked up.